# Is there a way to set up Google Apps Script trigger to be based on the edit of one of multiple spreadsheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I want to send an email when one of three spreadsheets have been edited. I have set up a trigger in the UI that runs a function on edit for one spreadsheet, but how do I make it so it runs on edit for one of three spreadsheets?

One solution is I put the function in scripts for each file and set up separate triggers, but is there a way to do this without having three scripts?

When I say spreadsheet, I mean a google sheets file

Comment: Here:  `you mean I want to send an email when one of three spreadsheets` you most likely mean sheets. You have different sheets and not different spreadsheet files.

Comment: no, i mean files. It confuses me too. In excel, you'd say workbook, but it doesn't seem to be called that in Google. I'll change it to spreadsheet file

Comment: spreadsheet is the file, sheet is the tab within the spreadsheet file.

Comment: I just realised the title says sheets so i'll change that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to make that a single on edit trigger, simple or installable, be triggered by the edits made on several spreadsheets.

One option is to use code to create multiple triggers to run the same function, one trigger for each spreadsheet.

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Comment: Thanks Ruben. This is super useful. Do you know if a trigger can be run based on when a BigQuery table is modified or created?

Comment: @user147529 Google Apps Script hasn't triggers for that. I don't if the BigQuery service has triggers.

Answer (score 1):

If the information required isn't time sensitive,   Create a [time based trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) on a [standalone script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone), which checks each of the three spreadsheet files every hour or so for modifications and sends a email, if modifications are inferred.  It is possible to use [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties)

- to store [last modified date time](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getlastupdated) and compare it to the current modified date time.
- get last row of sheet and compare it to last row currently, if data is added in that format.