# Add the time when one google sheets document is modified to another sheets document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have one sheet for a group of people. I'm trying to make a script so that whenever they edit the sheet, the time that they last edited will show up in a sheet in another document.

A sample row from the group sheet looks like this:

```
col1|...|col10|person name|...|col17
```

and the sheet that the time should be going to looks like this:

```
person name|col2|...|col10|date last edited.
```

this is the code that I've been trying and it is not working so far:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var time = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/Toronto"})

  var ID = "sheet ID"; //The ID for the second sheet goes here
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.OpenById(ID);
  var target = sheet.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var lastColumn = target.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = target.getLastRow();
  var range = target.getRange(1,1,lastRow, lastColumn);
  var data = range.getValues();
  
  var userEmail = e.user.getEmail();
  var array = userEmail.split(".");
  var firstName = array[0];
  
  var secondSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRowSecond = secondSheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumnSecond = secondSheet.getLastColumn();
  var secondRange = secondSheet.getRange(1,1,lastRowSecond, lastColumnSecond);
  var secondData = secondRange.getValues();
  var nameRow = secondData[row-1];
  var nameColumn = nameRow[10];
  var secondPersonarray = nameColumn.split(" ");
  var secondPersonFirstName = secondPersonarray[0];
  
  
  
  
  for (var i=1; i<lastRow; i++) {
    var sheetRow = data[i];
    var name = sheetRow[0].split(" ");
    var firstNameSheet = name[0];
    if ((firstName == firstNameSheet) && (firstName == secondPersonFirstName)) {
      target.getRange(sheetRow, 10).setValue(time);
    }                           
  }
}
```

I've done something similar, only with one document, so I know the problem isn't with the time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to set up Google Apps Script trigger to be based on the edit of one of multiple spreadsheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63450809/is-there-a-way-to-set-up-google-apps-script-trigger-to-be-based-on-the-edit-of-o)

Comment: @MariosKaramanis hmm, I think. So the solution is to run a script in each spreadsheet?